# Print IFrame content generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, printing

I am trying to print a HTML page in IFrame generated dynamically, with this code bellow:

```
var jFrame = $("<iframe name='ifm' src='{0}'>".format(url));

jFrame.css("width", "1px")
    .css("height", "1px")
    .css("position", "absolute")
    .css("left", "-9999px")
    .appendTo($("body:first"));

var objFrame = window.frames['ifm'];
$(objFrame).on('load', function () {
    // Only for testing
    console.log(window.frames['ifm'].document.body);

    objFrame.focus();
    objFrame.print();
});

setTimeout(
    function () {
        jFrame.remove();
    },
    (30 * 1000)
);
```

but when I click to print it, it prints a blank page with only header and footer.
The moment that this line is executed: `console.log(window.frames['ifm'].document.body);`, it prints the iframe body's content correctly, so I assume the iframe's content is loaded, but it is still printing a blank page.

Comment: What is the `format(url)` ?

Comment: @AliSoltani it will populate the iframe's src attribute.

Comment: Would you add a fiddle for your code like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/xjsobztk/)?